# Pythonのオーバーライドしたメソッドに印をつける方法

Tags: python, python3

Pythonで、オーバーライドしたメソッドに、明示的に印をつけることはできないでしょうか？
（Javaの@overrideアノテーションのようなもの、Pythonにはないでしょうか？）

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def my_method(self):
        """This is an abstract method."""
        pass

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
#   @override ←こんな感じの印(デコレータ)はつけられないですよね？
    def my_method(self):
        """Override the abstract method to do something else."""
        # ↑かわりにDocStringに記載するのが一般的でしょうか？どんな文言にしていますか？
        print("Hello, world!")
```

Comment: この辺の記事がどちらも古いですが何かヒントになるかも。[Why no @override decorator in Python to help code readability? \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34520985/9014308), [In Python, how do I indicate I'm overriding a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1167617/9014308) 出来るか否かよりも何のために如何したいかといったことをもう少し詳しく書いた方が良いと思われます。[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701)かもしれませんし。

Comment: ありがとうございます。@overrideは、可読性の向上、バグの防止などを目的としています。docstring のコメントで十分な場合があることも理解できました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `@override` ←こんな感じの印(デコレータ)はつけられないですよね？

適当に `override decorator` を作ってしまえばよいでしょう。

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import inspect

class BaseClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def my_method(self):
        """This is an abstract method."""
        pass

def override(method):
    def _override(*args, **kwargs):
        cls = getattr(inspect.getmodule(method), method.__qualname__.split('.', 1)[0], None)
        assert(any(method.__name__ in dir(c) for c in cls.__bases__))
        method(*args, **kwargs)
    return _override

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    @override
    def my_method(self):
        """Override the abstract method to do something else."""
        print("Hello, world!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DerivedClass().my_method()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。なければ作るケースだったのですね。

Answer (score 1):

[a.]@wrapsデコレータを追加しました。
[b.]戻り値を戻すようにしました。
[c.]型チェックを入れました。

以下のような感じになりました。

```
from functools import wraps

def override(method):
    """オーバーライドしているかチェックする。"""
    # [a.]
    @wraps(method)
    def _override(*args, **kwargs):
        # [c.]
        assert hasattr(method, '__qualname__'), f'Type Error.'
        cls = getattr(inspect.getmodule(method), method.__qualname__.split('.', 1)[0], None)
        assert any(method.__name__ in dir(c) for c in cls.__bases__), f'Not overridden. Method:[{method.__name__}]'
        # [b.]
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return _override
```

Answer (score 0):

【参考】
クラスの中に、クラスを定義し、継承関係がある場合でも、動作するようにしました。
（以前の回答例では、ネストしたクラスが含まれていると動作しませんでした。）

```
from typing import Any
from typing import Callable
import functools
import inspect


def get_attribute(obj, attribute_text: str, delimiter: str = '.') -> Any:
    """区切り文字で区切られた文字列を分割し、対応するattributeを取得する。"""
    attributes = attribute_text.split(delimiter)
    for attr in attributes:
        if not hasattr(obj, attr):
            return None
        obj = getattr(obj, attr)
    return obj


def get_class(func: Callable) -> Any:
    """指定したメソッドが所属しているクラスを取得する"""
    mod = inspect.getmodule(func)
    attribute_text = func.__qualname__.rsplit('.', 1)[0]  # RootClass.ChildClass.method
    return get_attribute(mod, attribute_text)


def is_override(func: Callable) -> bool:
    """Overrideされているか判定する"""
    assert hasattr(func, '__qualname__'), f'Type Error.'
    cls = get_class(func)
    assert cls is not None, 'cls is None.'
    # 複数の親クラスのそれぞれにdirを実行し、同名のメソッド・属性がないか判定する。
    for base_class in cls.__bases__:
        if func.__name__ in dir(base_class):
            return True
    return False


# デコレータ
def override(func: Callable) -> Callable:
    """Overrideされているか判定する"""
    checked = False  # 多重チェック防止フラグ

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal checked
        if not checked:
            assert is_override(func), f'Not overridden. Method:[{func.__name__}]'
            checked = True
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

以下、利用例です。

```
################################################################################
# テスト用クラス
class Root():
    class Base():
        def print(self):
            print('BaseClass')

    class Child(Base):
        @override
        def print(self):
            print('SubClass')


################################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Root.Child()
    test.print()
```